# Analyzing performance difference in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

In the constructor I have  piece of code which does the following:

**code snippet 1**

```
for (unsigned i=0; i<n; ++i) { 
    auto xIdIt = _originIdSet.find(xIds[i]);
    auto yIdIt = _originIdSet.find(yIds[i]);
    if (xIdIt == _originIdSet.end()) { _originIdSet.insert(xIds[i]); }
    if (yIdIt == _originIdSet.end()) { _originIdSet.insert(yIds[i]); }
}
```

`_originIdSet` is of the type `std::unordered_set<uint32_t>`
`xIds` and `yIds` is of the type `std::vector<uint32_t>`

xIds and yIds contain lots of duplicate entries, e.g.

`xIds = {1,2,1,2,3,5,....}`
`yIds = {2,3,4,1,4,1,....}`

`xIds[i]` never equals `yIds[i]`

I'm compiling with gcc 5.30 as follows: `g++ -g -Wall -m64 -O3 -std=c++11`

I've been profiling how much time this piece of code (i.e. code snippet 1) takes when `n` equals 10k^2 and I've found that if I change the code to:

**code snippet 2**

```
for (unsigned i=0; i<n; ++i) { 
    // We cannot insert duplicates in a set so why check anyway
    _originIdSet.insert(xIds[i]);
    _originIdSet.insert(yIds[i]);
}
```

It will be around 5 seconds slower (total run code-snippet 1 takes around 15 seconds).

I'm wondering what is the underlying reason for the performance decrease. My first guess would be that this is caused due branch optimization (excellent explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array)), however I believe it doesn't make sense that in this situation branch optimization would only be applied if an if/else conditions is used. Hopefully somebody can clarify what is happening here.

Comment: 5 seconds slower than what? Also try making 2 separate loops, one for each array.

Comment: 5 seconds slower than the first code snippet. I don't see any underlying reason for using 2 separate loops, please clarify.

Comment: n is undefined.

Comment: n is not undefined, as I'm explaining above, n equals 10k. Obviously I'm not showing the entire original code as this would not be relevant for the question.

Comment: _5 seconds slower_: if the first version take 1000 seconds, then 5 seconds slower is not a big deal, but if the first version takes 10 seconds then it _is_ a big deal. Please be more specific.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your generated assembly as GCC seems to have gained the ability to optimizing empty allocations out. Please add your input code.

Comment: @Gio 5s compared to let's say 24h run is a negligible difference due to random factors. That is what the question of Sopel was about. 5s is a meaningless piece of info on it's own.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried using _originIdSet.insert( xIds.begin(), xIds.end() ) and  _originIdSet.insert( yIds.begin(), yIds.end() ) ?

Comment: @Aless, Yes I've also tried that, it is equally slower.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad. I tried to reproduce on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/uj7ksf) but basically got shorter assembly for the second one, which means OP's behavior is probably not reproducible.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi 1+ OP should really create an example, that people can copy-paste and analyze, that includes the data. Otherwise, it's just wild guessing. I can imagine `find` version being faster when there are dupes, because finding might be faster than hashing, especially if there is a few distinct elements. That wouldn't show in the assembly, but it's impossible to verify.

Comment: To the OP: use a profiler, probably based on hardware counter. `perf` can check if your guess about branch prediction is correct or not, by showing the number of branch hit and miss.

Comment: @luk, unfortunately I cannot include all the data, as this comes from a matrix with 10.000 * 10.000 entries, however I've edited the question in order to provide some more clarifications regarding the input. I understand this question is not 100% reproducible, however I hoped there was a logical explanation and that this should not be necessary (perhaps I'm wrong in that).

Comment: I created reproduced example with data and time meausurement here http://ideone.com/poQcPV (with check before insert) and here http://ideone.com/TWjWKu (without check before insert). I see ~5% of time difference 3200ms vs 3400ms

Comment: @Gio 2 loops so you don't jump as much through memory, better for cache

Comment: And if replace to array xIds and yIds to one array, than time is same for both cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is two samples:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned n = 10000000;
    unordered_set<uint32_t> _originIdSet;
    vector<uint32_t> xIds, yIds;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        xIds.push_back(rand() % n);
        yIds.push_back(rand() % n);
    }

    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        auto xIdIt = _originIdSet.find(xIds[i]);
        auto yIdIt = _originIdSet.find(yIds[i]);
        if (xIdIt == _originIdSet.end()) { _originIdSet.insert(xIds[i]); }
        if (yIdIt == _originIdSet.end()) { _originIdSet.insert(yIds[i]); }
    }

    auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "inserted " << _originIdSet.size() << " to " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end-start).count() << " milliseconds" << std::endl;
}
```

And without any checking:

```
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        _originIdSet.insert(xIds[i]);
        _originIdSet.insert(yIds[i]);
    }
```

I see ~5% of time difference 3200ms vs 3400ms.

But if i replace two array `xIds` & `yIds` to one array that contains all elements from both array I get same time for both cases and it works slowly than two array.

I think, that general reason, it is because method `find()` doesn't throw any exception and it is constant.
Modern cpu is able to do more than 1 instruction in one tact for each thread, than you get un-obviously parallel running of two `find()`.

Or, second possibilities, gcc is able to generate SSE code for calculation of 2 hash values and search 2 position in set in same moment for two calls of `find()`.

Comment: There's no reason to assume anything. Paste the code into godbolt and see for yourself what code gets generated.